SQL Server 2008 R2: Rebalance files of a database to a same size
I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database which consists of 4 physical files:

DB_0.mdf (200 GB)
DB_1.ndf (300 GB)
DB_2.ndf (500 GB)
DB_3.ndf (1300 GB)

No tables of this database have clustered indices.
Now I wish to rebalance the file size so that each of the 4 files has the same size of (200+300+500+1300)/4 = 575 GB.
This is a part of a bigger operation which ultimately will put each of these 4 files into their own separate disks in a bid to improving performance. To optimize disk storage (I don't want each disk has different sizes just because these files have different sizes) and performance (Files with equal size with equal auto-increment would make the "proportional filling" algorithm performs best), I would like to make these file size equal first.
Based on the information from the Internet it seems DBCC SHRINKFILE with EMPTYFILE option is a good candidate, but what I have read so far concerns to rebalance one single file to multiple files; not the case I am now facing.
Please advise what would be the simplest approach to deal with this tasks.

Just change the file sizes in ssms? I'd probably increase the others first and then decrease the big one, if you have the space

Based on the information from the Internet for example? There are no articles on "rebalancing", there are articles on redistributing. Why do you think you need to redistribute the data? What do you hope to achieve? No tables of this database have clustered indices. that's the real problem. Along with using a database version that reached End Of Life 5 years ago

Wait a minute, this sounds a lot like an XY problem. [Edit] the question and explain why you want to make the files the same size. What's the underlying issue that you are trying to resolve anyway?

Just a note that shrinking heap tables will take a very very long time (perhaps 10-50 times longer than clustered tables). So if you decide to go the shrink ropute, be prepared to wait. It might be better to drop the nc indexes, do ALTER TABLE REBUILD and then add back the nc incexes.

I think you should focus your efforts on upgrading to a supported version of sql server. 2008 r2 has been fully unsupported for more than 5 years now.

@siggemannen the ultimate aim is to put each of these files into their own (virtual) disks respectively. But before doing so, because I know data are store in these files using "proportional refill" algorithm, I wish to make all of them into equal size first. Hence my question.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for pointing it out, but I think "rebalancing" and "redistributing" are quite similar.... Just I found no articles in the Internet addresses my case here. Yes, no table in this database have clustered indexes because this database is practically a data warehouse where lots of INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE happen so cluster indexes would only drag down the performance... However, most of the tables do have non-clustered indexes... Before doing UPSERT operations all these non-clustered indexes are dropped and then all non-clustered indexes will then be rebuilt afterwards.

@TiborKaraszi Actually this database functions as a data warehouse where every day all non-clustered indices are dropped before performing UPSERTs, and then they are all rebuilt afterwards. So DROP INDEX and ALTER TABLE REBUILD are done everyday yet there have been no rebalancing happening so far ...

@SeanLange I have been fully aware of this 2008 R2 issue; but because this SQL Server contains databases and SSIS and SSAS and SSRS (integrated with SharePoint 2010) and because I am the only one person for looking after this old server (all of my predecessors are gone before I joined this company), so I don't think a migration could be smoothly done with just myself. Hence I am currently focusing on optimizing this old server first.

@vonPryz My questions edited. Thanks.

@HandsomePig i think my answer stands, shrinking will put them in correct size. You can always move them to new disks later. Maybe I'm missing something though

@HandsomePig there are a lot of articles actually, and the services you mentioned do use and actually depend on clustered indexes. There are no articles for the specific bad situation of your server though. BTW saying that SP2010 has no clustered indexes means someone meddled with undocumented databases.

this database is practically a data warehouse where lots of INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE happen so cluster indexes would only drag down the performance this isn't even WRONG, on almost every subsentence. Says the 2-time SQL Server and 2-time SharePoint MVP. In a data warehouse data is typically append-only. All fact tables have a date, which makes a clustered index on the dimension fields not only natural, but the fastest option. Using autonumbering means new dimension and fact rows are appended at the end, as they should.

Right now performance suffers because there are no clustered indexes. The server doesn't load individual rows, it loads entire data or index pages at a time. A clustered index defines the physical storage order, which means nearby rows are stored in the same data page. By not having a clustered index, which specifies the storage order, you're forcing the server to load far more data pages than it has to

@HandsomePig - do you already have existing performance issues that you're trying to solve?  If so, I'd suggest separating out to separate "virtual" disks is unlikely to be the solution you need.  (Ultimately, I'm going to guess that your "virtual" disks are probably all assigned to the same actual physical disk, so really there's very little - if anything - to be gained by having separate "virtual" disks...you may gain benefits in the order of a few milliseconds, but that would likely be all).  I'd suggest trying to identify problematic queries and fix them

@PanagiotisKanavos That's why I said that is "practically" a data warehouse... I cannot agree with you more that operations of data warehouse should always be APPEND; and slowly changing dimension type 2 should be used for all dimension tables. However when I joined this company this database has been operating as it is and I just can't help it.

@Craig These 4 database files, together with database files of other databases, are all put into one single virtual disk which make this disk a huge performance bottleneck (judged from its average disk queue length). Hence I am thinking if separating these database files into their own disks would help. For the issue if additional "virtual" disks really help; well nowadays the practice of SANs and virtualizations by using systems like VMWare and HyperV are so pervasive it is not possible to ask for dedicated hardware...

@HandsomePig so pervasive it is not possible to ask for dedicated hardware that's not the case at all. It's easier to add more virtual disks that point to separate physical disks or RAID arrays. Never mind that a RADI5 is faster than individual disks or that NVMe are insanely fast. None of these arguments are valid. The real problem seems to be that the company doesn't want to pay for extra storage. And probably intends to discard whatever uses that old database

@HandsomePig, whilst I'm no virtualisation / SAN expert, by any means, from my own previous personal experience I'm pretty well certain that a single "virtual" disk vs. multiple "virtual" disks that are ultimately accessing the same physical disk via the same physical hardware channels are unlikely to have significantly different read/write performance.  Given you're stuck on SQL 2008, however, I'm going to guess that maybe the hardware is many years' old, so perhaps the overall demands on the hardware are exceeding its capabilities?

There are a few ways to achieve this depending on your edition of SQL, disk capacity on the server and tolerance for performance impacts/blocking.
Whatever method you opt for, one important factor is that you need to enable trace flag 1117 on the instance to ensure that future file growths are uniform.
NOTE: My answer is not touching on the 'why' you would want to do this or the fact that your SQL version is very out of date. This has been discussed in the comments, so I'm just providing some 'how' options
New Filegroup Method
This method involves creating a new filegroup with the required number of files and rebuilding all of your indexes and tables onto the new filegroup. This will shift the data into the new files in a proportional way and should result in fairly well-balanced data distribution.
Basic Process:

Create new filegroup (FG)
Add the required files on new disks in the new FG
Rebuild all clustered indexes on the new FG
For any heaps, create a temporary clustered index on the new FG, then drop the clustered index. This will leave the heap in place on the new FG.
Rebuild all non-clustered indexes on the new FG
Once the old files are confirmed empty, perform an EMPTYFILE on each NDF and remove it, then shrink the MDF file to an appropriate size.
Set the new FG as the default FG

If you have off-row LOB data, this will not move to the new FG when you rebuild the indexes/tables. To move this data, you can rebuild the affected indexes/tables using partitioning then rebuild without the partition to shift the LOB data.
Pros:

Lower risk since it mostly just involves index rebuilds
Generally quicker

Cons:

Requires all new objects to be built on the new FG (setting the default helps with this but doesn't guarantee it)
Requires Enterprise Edition for the partitioning hack if you have off-row LOB data

EMPTYFILE Method
This method involves creating a single temporary file that can hold all the data and emptying each of the existing files. Once they're all emptied and removed, you recreate the files at the same size in the new disks and then you empty the temporary file and it will redistribute data automatically.
Basic Process

Create a new NDF file on a disk with enough space to hold the entire database
Run DBCC SHRINKFILE with the EMPTYFILE option on each of the NDF files
As each file is emptied, remove the file from the database
Run DBCC SHRINKFILE with the EMPTYFILE option on the primary MDF file - This will fail eventually as some content from this file cannot be emptied. This is expected but should leave the file 99.9% empty
Shrink the primary file to recover the unused space
Create 3 new files at 1/4 of the total size. Resize the primary file to 1/4 of the total size
Run DBCC SHRINKFILE with the EMPTYFILE option on the temporary file to empty it and distribute the data across the other 4 files
Remove the temporary file

Pros:

Does not require Enterprise Edition
Does not change the default FG
Does not require rebuilding indexes
Process is interruptible, so you can run it over several days outside peak hours and simply stop/start the EMPTYFILE operations as needed

Cons:

Generally slower
Shrinking comes with some risks, which is why it is not a recommended practise


Thanks for your suggestion. In my case the database has over 100 tables, some of them are very large, yet none of them have clustered indexes, so I am afraid the clustered index approach is as suitable as the EMPTYFILE approach.

For the EMPTYFILE approach, in my case I have more than one ndf files. How can I ensure that, for ech ndf and the mdf file, the EMPTYFILE operation would only output its contents to the temp ndf file created in your first step?

You remove each one as you go - so EMPTYFILE on "DB_1.ndf", then remove "DB_1.ndf". Repeat for the other NDFs. You can't remove the MDF file, but once its emptied you can proceed from there. this will empty some of the contents of "DB_1.ndf" into the other NDF files (including the temporary file), but as you remove each one, the subsequent EMPTYFILE operations will only use the remaining files until you're emptying the MDF file into the temporary NDF file.
